# Passing a PHP variable from one document to the other

Tags: php

I would like to get a variable from a php document to another php document that run in the same page. For example:

doc1.php

```
$counter = 7;
```

doc2.php

```
$x = $counter;
```

How can I do this?
Is AJAX the only way to pass variables from one php to the other one or there is a faster way?

Comment: Use session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Barmar said,

doc1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['counter'] = '7';
?>
```

doc2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['counter'])){
    $x = $_SESSION['counter'];
    // $x = 7
}
?>
```

Regards.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about how $_SESSION works?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.